# GNU Radio OOT Block Using sndfile

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have created a couple of OOT blocks in c++ for GNU Radio. One block works fine, the other compiles but will not run in GNU Radio Companion due to some link error. I need (want) to use the sndfile library to write a wav file. My code compiles fine, but I get undefined symbols (the calls I'm making to sound methods). I assume I need to add something to my CMake files but this isn't an area I am familiar with (I do signal processing for work, not build scripts which someone else would deal with).

This is my .cmake file. Is there something here which I need to change so that Radio Companion will execute my block? And I have installed the library (sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev) and I did verify that the file libsndfile.so is in fact in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

```
find_package(PkgConfig)

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(PC_GR_CUSTOMMODULE gnuradio-customModule)

FIND_PATH(
    GR_CUSTOMMODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    NAMES gnuradio/customModule/api.h
    HINTS $ENV{CUSTOMMODULE_DIR}/include
        ${PC_CUSTOMMODULE_INCLUDEDIR}
    PATHS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
          /usr/local/include
          /usr/include
)

FIND_LIBRARY(
    GR_CUSTOMMODULE_LIBRARIES
    NAMES gnuradio-customModule sndfile
    
    HINTS $ENV{CUSTOMMODULE_DIR}/lib
        ${PC_CUSTOMMODULE_LIBDIR}
    PATHS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
          ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64
          /usr/local/lib
          /usr/local/lib64
          /usr/lib
          /usr/lib64
          
          )

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gnuradio-customModuleTarget.cmake")

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(GR_CUSTOMMODULE DEFAULT_MSG GR_CUSTOMMODULE_LIBRARIES GR_CUSTOMMODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(GR_CUSTOMMODULE_LIBRARIES GR_CUSTOMMODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Comment: Kevin: I tried these changes but no change. The name of the library is libsndfile.so. Should the NAMES entry be libsndfile?

Comment: I tried libsndfile and that didn't work either.